# How to read multiple bytes over I2C on Beaglebone Black with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, beagleboneblack, i2c

I'm trying to read temperature and humidity from an [Amphenol T9602 temperature/humidity sensor](https://www.cdiweb.com/datasheets/telaire-amphenol/T9602-07225-web.pdf). Essentially, you read it by reading 4 bytes in a row over I2C, where the first two bytes correspond to the humidity and the next two bytes correspond to the temperature. I've been able to get it to work using [this](https://github.com/AmphenolAdvancedSensors/Telaire/blob/T9602-ChipCap2/T9602.ino) Arduino sketch. Here is the important bit that actually reads the data:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x28);
Wire.write(0);
Wire.endTransmission();
## Heading ##
Wire.requestFrom(0x28, 4);
*a = Wire.read();
*b = Wire.read();
*c = Wire.read();
*d = Wire.read();
```

This is what a sample line of output looks like when I modify the showdata method to print a, b, c, d, and then the temperature and humidity:

```
101, 28, 97, 105, 22.78, 57.98
```

How can I replicate this functionality on the Beaglebone Black? I've tried using the smbus library, but all I've managed to accomplish is reading the first byte over and over. I can tell it's the first byte because it's always around 0x64 in standard conditions but gets higher if I increase the humidity. Same with kernel commands, although when I use `i2cget -y 2 0x28 0x0 w` to try and read 2 bytes I get something like 0xa865, where the first byte is way too high and the second byte is likely the first humidity byte. Also, I realize that this could probably be done more easily in another language, but it is important that this code is written in Python (preferably 3.x).

Comment: Found the answer myself. The SMBus.read_i2c_block_data(address, data_address, length) function accomplishes this